# Setting Google Map v3 size on map options

Tags: joomla, google-maps-api-3, tabs

I am trying to set up Google map (v3) inside Joomla tabs but there is display problems on map.

If i move away from tab where the map is and change back map canvas is grey and map is displayed only partially on left corner of map canvas.

Image with screen capture:

[image]

I get this worked on other site by setting map size on map parameters but there was used Google map version 2 and i could not find correct syntax for setting map size on version 3 map.

Map options are set in global variable.

```
var mapoptions = {
    zoom: 6,       
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 50),       
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    gridSize: 50,
    size(600, 700, 'px', 'px')
}
```

What is the correct syntax of map size or is there other solution for this?

I have tested resize function and playing with zoom but those was not helped.

Comment: @Cœur thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this solved by adding short delay (100ms) before map initializing function call.

Maybe map canvas did not get fully rendered before google map was accessing it.

Comment: Whilst this didn't answer the original question, I was having the exact same problem and this solution worked for me so thank you.