# Google Maps V3 Resize

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to gwt-maps-3.8.0 v3, if i try to display maps in multiple windows, it is not displaying fully, instead, it shows half of the map in window. Please check my code, and tell me whether anything is missing..

```java
public class MapTest extends HorizontalPanel {
    GoogleMap map;
    VerticalPanel mapVp = new VerticalPanel();

    public MapTest(){
        mapVp.setSize(String.valueOf(BodyPanel.bodyWidth - 505),
                      String.valueOf(BodyPanel.bodyHeight + 5));
        LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(30.440099, 36.843498);
        MapOptions myOptions = MapOptions.create();
        myOptions.setZoom(5);
        myOptions.setCenter(myLatLng);
        myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        myOptions.setMapTypeControl(true);
        map = GoogleMap.create(mapVp.getElement(), myOptions);
        add(mapVp)
    }
} 

TabItem tabItem = new TabItem("MapTest");
tabItem.add(new MapTest());
```

This shows the full map... When i do the same code and add that in another tab, it reduces the map size.. Trying to resolve this, pls help...
i.e, Again initializing the tabitem and trying to add the same page in other tab as

```java
tabItem = new TabItem("MapTest");
tabItem.add(new MapTest());
```

Comment: Are the maps displayed in the same panel?

Comment: Yes... But i'm using the same code and adding that in tabs... For 1st page full map is displayed and for the second only half..

Comment: where is `BodyPanel` defined?

Comment: can you display the code?

Comment: I have modified the code, pls chk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a Delay in loading maps using GWT Timer.. Referred [Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735740/setting-google-map-v3-size-on-map-options-solved) Solution and implemented in GWT...
Here is [link](http://www.ameenit.blogspot.in/2013/02/maps-v3gwt-maps-380-using-gwt-240.html)